# error in jenkins while importing project from github

Tags: github, jenkins

Facing this error in Jenkins while importing a project from GitHub repository

Jenkins running on localhost server.

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h

Comment: Are you sure git installed and configured at this server?
Try to run this command from cmd and your get mo detailed message.

Comment: @whitediver Thanks for your valuable response..actually i was just missing my git.exe path ...that's why it was unable to get repository path..